# How to direct lambda expression to execute a particular method in a class

Tags: java, lambda

I have a runner class which takes Runnables or Callables in an overloaded method.

```
class MyController {
  public void run(Runnable command) {
  }

  public void run(Callable command) {
  }
}
```

Other classes which need to execute run method do

```
controllerInstance.run(() -> {...});
```

How does lambda expressions based code determine to call the run(Runnable) or run(Callable) ? Is there a way I change this default behavior ?

Comment: I'd suggest just making it explicit by renaming the second method `call()`.

There are ways to get it to work with the methods as named (as shown in answers below), but they all tend to lead to less elegant code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring to `java.lang.Runnable` and `java.util.concurrent.Callable`, if you return a value, it matches `Callable`, and if it doesn't return a value, it matches `Runnable`, so no extra qualification is needed.

```
controllerInstance.run(() -> { /*no return*/ }); // calls run(Runnable command)
controllerInstance.run(() -> { return null; });  // calls run(Callable command)
```

But, if needed, you can force the issue by casting.

```
controllerInstance.run((Runnable) () -> { /*no return*/ }); // calls run(Runnable command)
controllerInstance.run((Callable) () -> { return null; });  // calls run(Callable command)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the method signature that determines which type of lambda you need. 
So when is returned `void` the lambda method matches with a `Runnable` interface.
When is returned an Object the lambda method matches with the `Callable` interface.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

class MyController {
  public void run(Runnable command) {
    System.out.println("Runnable");

  }

  public void run(Callable command) {
    System.out.println("Callable");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    MyController myController = new MyController();

    myController.run(() -> { return "String"; }  );
    myController.run(() -> {});
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
Callable
Runnable
```

Comment: So your answer to "How to direct lambda" is to not use lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You can 'tag' a lambda with a casting expression, which will indicate what interfaces it should implement. For instance:

```
controllerInstance.run((Runnable) () -> {...});
```

Just note that `Callable` actually has a return value, while `Runnable` does not, which method resolution takes into account. I found that as long as the block or expression of the lambda body does return a value, the `Callable` overload is used. If the call really is ambiguous, you get an error and can use an explicit cast.